# How to use columns of array item in delete_if?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

I want to delete certain items from an array when they meet a condition. I read that this is possible with `delete_if` or `reject`, but how can I access the columns/properties of that item.

For example if I want to delete all items from an array which id's are higher than 10, I would want to use something like this:

```
@randomArray.delete_if { |i| i.id > 10}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: You have a piece of code, why don't you try it out?

Comment: I have, but he can't find any properties from the item

Comment: can you share your array? What `@randomArray` looks like?

Comment: May be you have an array of hashes, then access the item properties with `i[:id]` or `i["id"]`. We need to see `@randomArray`.

Comment: Sorry for not answering sooner had some issues with pc. `@registers = Register.order("created_at DESC")`. the @register is the randomArray

Comment: Which rails version do you use? With rails 3.2 it should work. For rails 4 see [this](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/12140) and try `@randomArray.to_a.delete_if { |i| i.id > 10}`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that will work, but one thing that can be surprising is that, for example, in your case, @random_array will not be modified; rather, the delete_if method will return a new array with the undesired items deleted.

If you want to modify @random_array, then you can call `reject!` instead of `reject` or `delete_if`.  There is no `delete_if!` method, so you need to use `reject!`.